# Moving a file containing a space in ruby using FileUtils

Tags: ruby, file

I'm using Mac OS X and I'm trying to write a little script that moves a file to a specific folder. I'm using the FileUtils API since I don't want to run system specific commands (system("mv a b").

The script looks something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'rubygems'
require 'escape'
require 'fileutils'

absolut_input_filename = Escape.shell_single_word ARGV[0]
move_folder = Escape.shell_single_word "/move/to/folder"      
FileUtils.mv absolut_input_filename, move_folder
```

As long as the input filename contains no space, everything works fine. But as soon as I put in a file with a space the error output is something like this:

./scripts/success /path/to/file\ with\ space

```
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1418:in `stat': No such file or directory - '/path/to/file with space' (Errno::ENOENT)
        from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1418:in `block in fu_each_src_dest'
        from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1432:in `fu_each_src_dest0'
        from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1416:in `fu_each_src_dest'
        from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:504:in `mv'
        from ./scripts/success:8:in `<main>'
```

For escaping I use the 'escape' gem in version 0.0.4 in which the `shell_single_word` looks like this:

```
  def shell_single_word(str)
    if str.empty?
      "''"
    elsif %r{\A[0-9A-Za-z+,./:=@_-]+\z} =~ str
      str
    else
      result = ''
      str.scan(/('+)|[^']+/) {
        if $1
          result << %q{\'} * $1.length
        else
          result << "'#{$&}'"
        end
      }
      result
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can just not use escape

```
require 'fileutils'
absolut_input_filename = ARGV[0]
move_folder = "/move/to/folder"
FileUtils.mv absolut_input_filename, move_folder
```

Comment: More precisely `FileUtils` expects an unescaped string, so things start to break as soon as leifg escapes a space. If he passes it through unescaped (as in your example) it will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I don't actually know from Ruby, so take this with a grain of salt, but I know the underlying OS primitives inside and out, and from C you can do this with [`rename(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/rename).  Therefore, from Ruby, you *should* be able to do this with `File.rename`, which requires no quoting at all.  Try this:

```
#! /usr/bin/env ruby

tomove = ARGV[0]
target = "/path/to/target/folder"

File.rename(tomove, File.join(target, File.basename(tomove)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved using soft links:

```
ln -s ~/Folder\ with\ spaces/foo/ ./foo
```

now i can use FileUtils commands without problems:

```
FileUtils.cp("bar.txt", "foo/foobar.txt")
```

Hope will help!